# Deploy Spring-based web app in Undertow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, undertow

I am trying to migrate our Spring-based web app from Tomcat 8 to Undertow.

We use Spring's WebApplicationInitializer for the programmatic configuration of Spring-MVC and HibernateTransactionManager.

There is a `ServletContainerInitializerInfo` class [(Javadoc)](http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/io/undertow/undertow-servlet/1.0.14.Final/undertow-servlet-1.0.14.Final-javadoc.jar-unzip/io/undertow/servlet/api/ServletContainerInitializerInfo.html) that seems to serve my purpose, e.g I can instantiate it and then follow the steps given in Undertow docs [(link)](http://undertow.io/documentation/servlet/deployment.html) to start the server:

```
ServletContainerInitializerInfo sciInfo = 
    new ServletContainerInitializerInfo(containerInitializerClass,
        instanceFactory, handlesTypes);

DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
    .addServletContainerInitalizer(sciInfo);

DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer()
    .addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();

PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/myapp"))
    .addPrefixPath("/myapp", manager.start());

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(path)
        .build();
server.start();
```

The problem is that I don't know what to substitute for `instanceFactory` and `handlesTypes` arguments in call to `ServletcontainerInitializerInfo` constructor. In addition, the name of the `addServletContainerInitalizer` method is mis-spelled (should be Initializer instead of Initalizer).

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undertow uses `InstanceFactory<T>` as an extension point for dependency injection or other customization of an instance of a given class after instantiation.

The `handlesTypes` argument would be the set of all classes corresponding to the [`@HandlesTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html) annotation on your servlet container initializer.

If your initializer has no `@HandlesTypes` and does not require dependency injection, you can simply try this:

```
MyInitializer initializer = new MyInitializer();

InstanceFactory<MyInitializer> instanceFactory 
    = new ImmediateInstanceFactory<>(initializer);

ServletContainerInitializerInfo sciInfo = 
    new ServletContainerInitializerInfo(MyInitializer.class,
        instanceFactory, new HashSet<Class<?>>());
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to compile and start the application. I am having another issue though: Undertow cannot locate Spring's WebApplicationInitializer instance. I will probably post a separate question for that.

Comment: Got it working. I had to specify my concrete implementation of WebApplicationInitializer in HandlesTypes list. Thanks again!